# How do I write a :target selector for more than just the id

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a combination of selectors that would allow me to access the thumbnail list following the :target selected image1?

p.s. if that would help thumbnail list could be moved into gallery list as a last element... Then maybe I could somehow use `~` selector?

```
<div id="gallery-list">

    <div>
      <div id="thumbnail"> <a href="#image1"><img src="image1_thumb.png"></a> </div>
      <div id="image1" class="overlay"><img src="image1.png"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="I_WANT_TO_SHOW_THIS_ALONG_WITH_image1_OVERLAY" class="thumbnail-list">
        <img src="image1_thumb_mini.png">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have a little bit hard time understanding what your meaning, perhaps show your current selector to make it a little bit easier to get ur point. if i had to make a guess i'd say your want to do `:target #thumbnail-list`

Comment: this is not possible with only CSS, you can do it with jQuery. there is no backward in CSS, you need to move `thumbnail-list` to be sibling

Comment: @Breezer what I'm asking - is there a way to access thumbnail list with :target?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> p.s. if that would help thumbnail list could be moved into gallery list as a last element... Then maybe I could somehow use `~` selector?

Like as a sibling of `#image1`? If so, yes that will work. The selector you would use would then be `#image1:target ~ .thumbnail-list`. Either remove that parent `div` that doesn't have a class, or move `.thumbnail-list` into that `div` if it needs to be there.

But with your current structure, it's not possible because `.thumbnail-list` is a sibling of the *parent* of `#image1`, and [there is no parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector).

Comment: I already learned there is no parent :)
And I'm not that much attached to the structure - so that's why I was thinking that `~` could help! I'll try it out~! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can use this selector `#image1:target ~ .thumbnail-list`, if you change your HTML like this:

```
<div id="gallery-list">
    <div>
      <div id="thumbnail"> 
           <a href="#image1"><img src="image1_thumb.png"></a> 
      </div>

      <div id="image1" class="overlay">
           <img src="image1.png">
      </div>

      <div id="I_WANT_TO_SHOW_THIS_ALONG_WITH_image1_OVERLAY" class="thumbnail-list">
        <img src="image1_thumb_mini.png">
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```